# Set $_COOKIES['key'] in one file it can access, but in other can not query

Tags: php, cookies

I have a directory, under it there are two php files `index.php`, `index2.php`:

in the `index.php`:

```
<?php

$_COOKIE['constant_a']='A';
echo($_COOKIE['constant_a']);
```

in the `index2.php`:

```
<?php

echo($_COOKIE['constant_a']);
```

Firstly, I access the `http://localhost:63342/htdocs/index.php`, the browser will show the `A`.

but then I input the `index2.php`, `http://localhost:63342/htdocs/index2.php`:
there print Undefined Error:

> Notice: Undefined index: constant_a in /Users/sof/Desktop/htdocs/index.php on line 12

Why it do not shows the `A`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) instead of `$_COOKIE['constant_a']='A'` as:

```
setcookie('constant_a', 'A');
```

Comment: This works, but why `$_COOKIE['constant_a']='A'` do not work in this case? I have use `$_COOKIE['constant_a']` get value success.

Comment: It will set value for only that request. But in case of new request it will not available.

Comment: Hi, friend, I use the `setcookie('constant_a', 'A');

echo($_COOKIE['constant_a']);`  // there cannot use the `$_COOKIE['constant_a']` to get the cookie, why?

Comment: Because cookie always set for the next request not for current request. In current request, when response returns to browser, it asks to set cookie and available from next request.